# Analytical Badge still showing “FAQ”

Tags: support

I just noticed that the FAQ link at the top of the page is replaced with "help". However, the description of the Analytical Badge is still "Visited every section of the FAQ". Shouldn't this also be changed to "Visited every section of the helpcenter" or something like that?

Also how will this badge be awarded now? Do you have to click on every link in the helpcenter to get this badge or do you just have to take the tour now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the description of the analytical badge.

> Visited every section of the FAQ (retired)

There is a 'retired' in there. This means that the badge cannot be awarded anymore. 
This applies to all stackexchange sites, including stackoverflow.